# object is not a constructor node js

Tags: node.js, express

Hi i am writing the below code,

```
**mysql-model.js**
var mysqlModel = require('mysql-model');

var model = function(){
var MyAppModel = mysqlModel.createConnection({
    host                        : 'localhost',
    user                        : "root",
    password                    : "",
    database                    : "test",
});
return MyAppModel;
}
module.exports = model;

**leave.js**

var dbConnectionCreator = require('../utilities/mysqlConnection.js');
var mysqlModel = require('../utilities/mysql-model.js');
var object = mysqlModel.MyAppModel;
Leave = new object({tableName: "leave_history"});
```

I am getting the below error

**TypeError: object is not a constructor
    at Object. (C:\wamp\www\express-redux-sample-master\server\models\leave.js:7:9)**

Help me to solve the issue

Comment: Did you mean `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no properly `mysqlModel.MyAppModel` and thus it is `undefined`.  You don't assign a property of that name to the exports in `mysql-model.js`.  You did this:

```
module.exports = model;
```

which makes the exports object itself, your function.  And, that function is not a constructor function either, it's a normal function.

So, the way `mysql-model.js` is written, you could do:

```
let mysqlModel = require('../utilities/mysql-model.js');
let leave = mysqlModel();
```

Since exports is just a normal function, you need to just call it as a normal function.

Answer (score 0):

**mysql-model.js**

```
var mysqlModel = require('mysql-model');

var MyAppModel = mysqlModel.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "test",
});

module.exports = {MyAppModel};
```

**leave.js**

```
var dbConnectionCreator = require('../utilities/mysqlConnection.js');
var {MyAppModel} = require('../utilities/mysql-model.js');
Leave = new MyAppModel({tableName: "leave_history"});
```

Try the Above snippet, as much as i'm getting, it is an import/export confusion.

Comment: Thank you, could you please explain this

Comment: Just the documentation of mysql-model, its good.
And I've used ES6 syntax to pull a property out of a value. The Line `var {MyAppModel} = require('../utilities/mysql-model.js');` could also be written as `var MyAppModel = require('../utilities/mysql-model.js').MyAppModel;`